# Python finding best fit line

Tags: python

I am a high school student, and we need do a computer coding assignment, but I have some hard time on this, I am trying to print the answer on python 3.3.2, but it is not what I expect. How can I change the problem? I searched for the script but I still don't know what is the script... Is there some one who can teach me how to fix the script? I tried by adding () but it is still not working...
The question given is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUvcW.png)
And I tried to make the code which was [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8vKG.png)
but it says it is wrong... I tried few times with different scripts, but it is not working...

```
x=[1.0,2.0,3.0]
y=[1.0,3.0,4.0]
a=0
b=0
c=0
sumD=10
for n in range (1000):
    testA = -5.0+n/1000
    for k in range (1000):
        testB = -5.0+k/1000
        for z in range (1000):
            testC = -5.0+z/1000
            testSum=(testA*x[0]**2+testB*x[0]+testC-y[0])**2+(testA*x[1]**2+testB*x[1]+testC-y[1])**2+(testA*x[2]**2+testB*x[2]+testC-y[2])**2
            if testSum < sumD:
                a=testA
                b=testB
                c=testC
a
b
c
```

The code should tell me what is a, b and c is, then I will be able to plug into ax^2+bx+c (the function), and I will need to check my work on a website. The problem is that it is not showing a,b and c. I don't know how to fix it!

I tried to do:

```
print a
print (a)
print "a"
a
```

Those did not work

Comment: Copy paste your code in to this question properly formatted please. Also, please explain what part of your code is not behaving as you expect. Stating that something is simply not working is not helpful for the people who want to help you.

Comment: Rather than giving us your code in the from of an image (which makes it very hard for us to test), could you please paste your code in the post itself and format it nicely by using the shortcut `CTRL+K`?

Comment: Thanks for your respond

Comment: sorry, I'm new with this website

Comment: Great. Next step, instead of showing the question to your assignment, explain what your code should be doing. Explain what it is not doing and why you think it is not working. Be explicit about what you have tried and what kind of issues you are facing.

Comment: but I don't know why it is like this :(

Comment: Tiffany, there are a boatload of ways to find the answer. You haven't told us what you know how to do, either mathematically or in python. Do you know how to invert a matrix? Find the determinant of a matrix? Can you do recursion? Are you comfortable writing python? Is there a standard process your teacher has given you for finding these coefficients? What version of python? Are numpy or sympy allowed? We need to put ourselves in your shoes and give you help you can comprehend. So tell us what you know, what you have been told, and where you want this to go!

Comment: What @AustinHastings said.  (In particular, it seems unlikely that your teach asked you to do a billion iterations to search the parameter space for a least-squares estimate.)  
Please read How To Ask a Good Question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: So generally I have almost no idea about python, i just know little things about it like doing easy math.

Comment: I know how to do easy math on python but not too much, like adding or multiplying I can do it, but not coding. I have almost no idea about matrix on python... I am comfortable on writing python, I can briefly understand what it is going on on this kind of format, I mean in mine. the teacher said that the range and the 5 could be change according the answer I get is appropriated to what I should get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do because I don't understand your question that well.

Unfortunately, the code runs insanely slow. (It takes about 75 minutes to complete.) Mabey you should look for a different solution.
I copied it out for the image and got:

```
x = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
y = [1.0, 3.0, 4.0]
a = 0
b = 0
c = 0
sumD = 10

for n in range(1000):
    testA = -5.0 + n / 1000
    for k in range(1000):
        testB = -5.0 + k / 1000
        for z in range(1000):
            testC = -5.0 + z / 1000
            testSum = (testA*x[0]**2+testB*x[0]+testC-y[0])**2+(testA*x[1]**2+testB*x[1]+testC-y[1])**2+(testA*x[2]**2+testB*x[2]+testC-y[2])**2
            if testSum < sumD:
                a = testA
                b = testB
                c = testC

print(a) #This is the correct syntax to use
print(b)
print(c)
```

Comment: yes, it says "invalid syntax", is my macbook's problem?

Comment: Probably not, upload a screen shot of it and I'll look.

Comment: You should run your code in a window, press Ctrl + N to open one. This shows you where the error is and lets you save you code.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help you then. I'm not used to mac, so I thought it would show up. I really don't know why, it works for me, but like I said before try looking for a different method. It just takes too long to complete...

Comment: maybe it is a bad thing to ask but can you send the screenshot? @George Willcox

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ONFTJ.png the program runs, but nothing will happen until it ends.

Comment: thanks for your help, I will try to ask my professor later to see hoe can I do. If I find out the answer for it I will post on it... thanks